# How to pass different output from Choice state in AWS Step Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Let say part of my Step Function looks like next:

```
"ChoiceStateX": {
  "Type": "Choice",
  "Choices": [
    {
      "Variable": "$.value",
      "NumericEquals": 0,
      "Next": "ValueIsZero"
    }
  ],
  "Default": "DefaultState"
},
"ValueIsZero": {
  "Type" : "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:******:function:Zero",
  "Next": "NextState"
},
"DefaultState": {
  "Type" : "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:******:function:NotZero",
  "Next": "NextState"
}
```

Let assume that input to this state is:

```
{
   "value": 0,
   "output1": object1,
   "output2": object2,
}
```

My issue is that I have to pass `output1` to `ValueIsZero` state and `output2` to `DefaultState`. I know that it is possible to change `InputPath` in `ValueIsZero` and `DefaultState` states. But this way isn't acceptable for me because I am calling these states from some other states also.

I tried to modify `ChoiceStateX` state like next:

```
"ChoiceStateX": {
  "Type": "Choice",
  "Choices": [
    {
      "Variable": "$.value",
      "NumericEquals": 0,
      "OutputPath": "$.output1",
      "Next": "ValueIsZero"
    }
  ],
  "Default": "DefaultState"
}
```

I got next error in this case: *Field OutputPath is not supported*.

How is it possible to implement this functionality?

**PS:** In the current moment I am using 'proxy' states between ChoiceStateX and ValueIsZero/DefaultState where modifying the output.

I have checked:

- [Input and Output Processing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-input-output-processing.html)
- [Choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html)

but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it isn't possible to specify different `OutputPath` for one state.

The solution with proxy states doesn't look graceful.

I have solved this issue in another way in the state before `ChoiceStateX`. I am setting instances of different types in `output` property and only route it on `ChoiceStateX` state.

My input of `ChoiceStateX` state looks like:

```
{
   "value": value,
   "output": value==0 ? object1 : object2
}
```

End final version of `ChoiceStateX` state:

```
"ChoiceStateX": {
  "Type": "Choice",
  "Choices": [
    {
      "Variable": "$.value",
      "NumericEquals": 0,
      "Next": "ValueIsZero"
    }
  ],
  "OutputPath": "$.output",
  "Default": "DefaultState"
}
```

It is still isn't perfect, because I implement the same logic in two places.